# Writing unittest to create a file and then delete that file

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I have this method I created :

```
 public static bool DeleteFile(FileInfo fileInfo)
    {
        try
        {
            fileInfo.Delete();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            LogManager.LogError(exception);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Now I wrote the following unittest:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void DeleteFileSuccessFul()
    {
        string fileName = "c:\\Temp\\UnitTest3.txt";
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);

        File.Create(Path.Combine(fileName));

        bool success = FileActions.DeleteFile(fileInfo);

        Assert.IsTrue(success);
    }
```

This test fails because the file is in use by a different proces.
The test fails on het bool success = FileActions.DeleteFile(fileInfo); because the file is in use by a different process.

How can I change my test so it works ?

Comment: I don't get it. You want your test to pass when the DeleteFile has failed?

Comment: I want my test to pass when the DeleteFile did not fail. (Sorry maybe that wasn't clear). I also tried creating the file with the fileInfo I defined but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to call `Dispose` method on the `FileStream` object returned by the `File.Create` method to release the handle to that file:

```
[TestMethod]
public void DeleteFileSuccessFul()
{
    string fileName = "c:\\Temp\\UnitTest3.txt";
    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);

    using (File.Create(Path.Combine(fileName)))
    {
    }

    bool success = FileActions.DeleteFile(fileInfo);

    Assert.IsTrue(success);
}
```

**UPDATE:** `using` block provides a convenient syntax that ensures the `Dispose` method of an `IDisposable` object is get called after leaving the scope of the block even if an exception occurs. The equivalent to the above code could be re-written with `try-finally` block:

```
[TestMethod]
public void DeleteFileSuccessFul()
{
    string fileName = "c:\\Temp\\UnitTest3.txt";
    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);

    FileStream fileStream = null;
    try
    {
        fileStream = File.Create(Path.Combine(fileName));
    }
    finally
    {
        if (fileStream != null)
            fileStream.Dispose();
    }

    bool success = FileActions.DeleteFile(fileInfo);

    Assert.IsTrue(success);
}
```

Comment: +1 but you migth want to add that it's by using `using` *(pun intended)*, `Dispose` will get called.